# Python to identify the date of different formats from class string

Tags: python

I have text input . I need to find out if there is any date in this String. The challenges is that the date can be in a lot of different formats.

`datefinder.find_dates` is tried with txt input .The type of input data is seen

```
import datefinder

with open("Azurebill.txt") as open_file:

    data = open_file.read()
    data = data.upper()
    print('this type is:',  type(data))

def extractDate(input):

    matches = datefinder.find_dates(input)
    for match in matches:
        print ('The date match is ')
        return (match)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    b=extractDate(data)
    print(b)

Input[.txt]
------------
City Centre Durgapur (W. B. )
CIN:U15135DL 1991PLC046758
Ph. No. -08336967703
TIN NO. : 19200834072
STR NO. : AABCD5534AST002
INVOICE
Inv No 31416051984 ORD No 31416052092
Date: 11/09/16 7:26 POS No.
T31411
Staff : Ricky
Table
1
Cust.
Table 1
Token No: - 117
*DINE-IN*
THANK
```

### Actual Result:

```
this type is: <class 'str'>
The date match is
1991-06-11 00:00:00
```

### Expected result

```
The date match is 11/09/16
```

Comment: Will all dates be tagged with "Date: " as in your sample Input.txt?

Comment: no - not all input have Date tagged before and can be in different formats

Comment: Sounds like a job for regexes. Regices? Regular expressions, in any case.

Comment: What happens if you remove the line `CIN:U15135DL 1991PLC046758`?

Comment: I don't think this package does what it purports to do. At least not as well as the brief documentation would make it seem. If you use the optional arguments `source=True, index=True`, you'll see that it's returning ` 1991` at position 42 in your input. If you set the `strict=True`, it returns instead `5534` in the middle of your `"Str No."`.

Comment: it looks like the package expects natural language text input, and I suspect that your heavily abbreviated and formatted invoice data is simply **not** "natural language".